# Centering a group of objects in between other objects in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to center a group of buttons and labels between a navigation bar and UI View. I have tried creating a constraint to make the space from the button to the UI view more than 8. I have not been able to get it to work when trying this. How do I get the group of buttons to center? Below are some screenshots of what is happening and what I set. I have only used the storyboard interface to create the items and set the constraints. I would prefer a solution using the storyboard.

[Screen shot of iPhone XS/X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJMW1.png)

[Screen shot of iPhone XS Max](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJR0v.png)

[Screen shot of iPhone 8/7/6s/6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnAVY.png)

[Screen shot of iPhone SE/5s/5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYs2Z.png)

[Example of the constraints I set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO1pH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use stackViews.**

1, Create 4 horizontal stack view for you "lines". First select top 2 buttons, and add it to (horizontal) stackView. (Bottom-right corner on the storyboard editor). Do it with other lines as well.

[image: stackView]

2, Set the stackView's distribution settings to Fill equally and add custom spacing.

[image: stackViewSettings]

3, Add all the stackViews to one stackView (this will be vertical), and set it fill equally as well.

4, Set up constraints for all the stackViews (left: 0, right: 0)

[image: cons]

5, Select Main stack view and setup for horizontally and vertically centered.

[image: center]

Result

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview) available in Xcode / Interface Build as `Horizontal Stack View` and `Vertical Stack View`.

A vertical stack view can contain subviews and / or horizontal stack views.